# How to remove the rest of a string

Tags: php, string

If i have a string like so:

> Hello - Bye

How can i make php find and delete a specifc character and the rest of the string on wards

like an example

> Hello - Bye

find the character -

and be left with the string

> Hello

Answer (score 6):

Use [`strpos`](http://docs.php.net/strpos) to find the position of the first occurence of a substring and then [`substr`](http://docs.php.net/substr) to just get everything up to that position:

```
$pos = strpos($str, '-');
if ($pos !== false) {  // strpos returns false if there is no needle in the haystack
    $str = substr($str, 0, $pos);
}
```

And if you have PHP 5.3 and later, you could also use the [`strstr` function](http://docs.php.net/strstr) with the third parameter set to *true*.

Comment: if your string has more then one hyphen in it, you could also use strrpos, to get the last matching occurrence of the the specified character, depending on your requirements

Comment: Damn, wish I could upvote you again for the extra bit of info about 5.3, very interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$pieces = explode('-', 'Hello - Bye', 2);
print $pieces[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = preg_replace('!-.*$!', '', 'Hello - Byte');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$somestring="Hello - Bye";
$array=preg_split("/\s+-\s+/",$somestring,2);
print $array[0]."\n";
```